# Automating file generation

Tags: reactjs, webstorm

I am curious to see how can we automate file/directory creation in WebStorm. For example, to create a component, right click on Component folder and run some macro/command and it will create folders for action creators, dispatchers, containers, reducers etc, with some code files to begin with.

Further, we may change what exactly is being generated to meet future requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Not currently possible, please vote for [IDEA-141225](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-141225) and [IDEA-91565](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-91565).

You can try a custom plugin (http://ceh9.github.io/PackageTemplates/), or develop your own one